# mysql on cpanel remote access from java dasktop application: Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, cpanel, remote-access

How can I establish a connection to a MySQL database on cPanel from a Java desktop application using Hibernate? My current connection string is:

`jdbc:mysql://ipaddress_to_cpannel/databasename?useSSL=true&requireSSL=true&verifyServerCertificate=false`

The username and password are set in the Hibernate config file and belong to the user I created on cPanel.

Javafx desktop application have to connect to mysql database on cpanel, do I need to consider ssl if yes how

Comment: You'll be lucky if that's allowed. Most cPanel hosting would not allow remote access.

Comment: I am not aware, so its impossible?

Comment: Not impossible maybe, but certainly security considerations would forbid it normally. I remember having the same using case with cheap hosting so wrote a server-side script to access it and invoked it with http. That's not going to fly with Hibernate. But you should be asking yourself why you'd want to expose your own app. Client-side access is really not securable in any practical way

Comment: I have a desktop application I want to use database on cpanel,

Comment: I know that - hence my lengthy comment ;)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Javafx desktop application have to connect to mysql database on cpanel, do I need to consider ssl if yes how

Comment: Likely irrelevant - it won't solve the access problem